# Constraints problem with HTML element drag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I made script for dragging element around my react application in the way that limits are parent container. I achieved what I want but not in the way I want. I want when I reach limits to block that axis from trying to go further to avoid this annoying effect of script calculating and returning div in position.

```js
const drag = (id) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    const parent = element.parentNode;

    let newState = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    let oldState = { x: 0, y: 0 };

    const dragElement = (e) => {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      oldState.x = e.clientX;
      oldState.y = e.clientY;
      document.onmouseup = stopDrag;
      document.onmousemove = startDrag;
    };

    const startDrag = (e) => {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      newState.x = oldState.x - e.clientX;
      newState.y = oldState.y - e.clientY;
      oldState.x = e.clientX;
      oldState.y = e.clientY;

      const handleX = () => {
        let x = 0;

        if (element.offsetLeft < 0) {
          x = 0;
        } else if (element.offsetLeft + element.offsetWidth > parent.offsetWidth) {
          x = parent.offsetWidth - element.offsetWidth;
        } else {
          x = element.offsetLeft - newState.x;
        }

        return `${x}px`;
      };

      const handleY = () => {
        let y = 0;

        if (element.offsetTop < 0) {
          y = 0;
        } else if (element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight > parent.offsetHeight) {
          y = parent.offsetHeight - element.offsetHeight;
        } else {
          y = element.offsetTop - newState.y;
        }

        return `${y}px`;
      };

      element.style.top = handleY();
      element.style.left = handleX();
    };

    const stopDrag = () => {
      document.onmouseup = null;
      document.onmousemove = null;
    };

    if (document.getElementById(element.id + "Header")) {
      document.getElementById(element.id + "Header").onmousedown = dragElement;
    } else {
      element.onmousedown = dragElement;
    }
  };

drag("test");
```

```css
.parent {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
position: absolute;
inset: 16px;
background: red;
}

.draggable {
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="draggable" id="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you also show us your html-code and put it in a snippet please?

Comment: I created snippset to simulate my problem. pull green square to any edge